# I am confused about the word's positioning in the following sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality

> After some time he appeared in a hall which had a 'long rectangular shaped table', which seemed empty.

Should the correct one be a ' rectangular-shaped long table? Also, about the part after coma, should I use 'seems' or 'seemed'. Please also teach me if I have any other grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule about the order in which adjectives appear, but there are some general 'rules of thumb' that would suggest your example is fine the way it is.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) suggests the following order for adjectives:

1. opinion
2. size
3. physical quality
4. age
5. colour
6. origin
7. material
8. type
9. purpose

*Size* is suggested before any other physical quality, such as the *shape*, which means "long (size), rectangular (shape)" is fine. (No need to say "shaped")

---

"Seemed" is the past tense of "seem", and as your sentence has the words "appeared" and "had" in the past tense, "seemed" follows the correct tense.

Comment: Isn't 'rectangular shaped' redundant?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is... I overlooked that.

Comment: To clarify for learners, 'rectangular' means the same as 'rectangle shaped', like 'circular' means 'circle shaped'.

Comment: Wow this is the best learning site I ever visited. Thank you for your time and your answer.